# The problem about the Riemann integral(f(x)=0)

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$f$ is continuous function on $[a, b]$. If there exists $K>0$ s.t. $|f(x)|\leq K\int_a^x|f(t)|dt$ for all $x$, then $f(x)=0$.

I am trying to use Mean Value Theorem for integrals, but it is hard to prove it. Can you give me some hints?